# Move SharePoint Online Site to another Region? Slow in North America, fast in EMEA

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a HQ in Europe and branches in EMEA, North America and APAC. 
Each branch has own SharePoint Online sites.

North America (Detroit) complains about slow loading of their SPO Team-Site. 
This Team-Site is fast when accessed from EMEA.

There is a Start-SPOSiteContentMove applet (https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/office365/enterprise/move-sharepoint-between-geo-locations).

[image]

At this point we have a single subdomain COMPANYNNAME.sharepoint.com.

**Do we need a new address like COMPANYNAME-US.sharepoint.com for this? How can I create one?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Online (and Office 365) is structured in Tenants.

The Tenant URL is TENANT.sharepoint.com.

When creating a Tenant you can choose your Tenant base location.

You can move a SharePoint Online Site to another Tenant with another location if you want to set a different region of the world to be able to use the site perfomantly. (See Start-SPOSiteContentMove commandlet).

There is no other way to move a single site within a tenant to another region of the world.

**Move a SharePoint site to another region of the world:**

1. Create New Tenant (e.g. company-US.sharepoint.com) and set North America region
2. Move the site with Start-SPOSiteContentMove